# calling function in a label in tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i am using a tkinter GUI. this function is behind a button. can i call the whole function's output to be displayed in a LABEL(inside a frame).

```
def rules(value):
    if no_of_EG==6:
        print("Readability is EXTREMELY GOOD")
    elif no_of_EG==5:
        print("Readability is VERY GOOD")
    .
    .
    .
    // and so on many rules
rules(mapped)
```

tkinter code:

```
leftFrame=Frame(window, bd=2, width=180, height=550)
leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

button5 = Button(leftFrame, text ="Rules", command=lambda:rules(mapped))
```

if i do this:

```
def rules(value):
    if no_of_EG==6:
        print("Readability is EXTREMELY GOOD")
        global a
        a = 'Readability is EXTREMELY GOOD'
rules(mapped)  

def MF():
    MFlabel1 = Label(bottomRightFrame, bg="black", fg="white", textvariale=a)
    MFlabel1.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=E)

button5 = Button(leftFrame, text ="Rules", command=MF)
```

its a very very long process as there are more than 40 rules. so how can i call a whole function output?

Comment: So pretty much you want the text printed in the 'rules' function to be written in a label?

Comment: yes. Any other solution instead of assigning each rule's text to a new variable and than print in a label.

Comment: Do you mind posting your full code? I have done a lot with tkinter so I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `widget.config(text=variable)` or `widget['text']=variable` method:

```
def MF():
    MFlabel1 = Label(bottomRightFrame, bg="black", fg="white", textvariale=a)
    MFlabel1.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=E)
    rules(mapped)

def rules(value):
    if no_of_EG==6:
        print("Readability is EXTREMELY GOOD")
        global a
        a = 'Readability is EXTREMELY GOOD'
    MFlabel1['text'] = a
    #MFlabel1.config(text=a)     you can use the above line or this line.

button5 = Button(leftFrame, text ="Rules", command=MF)
```

Comment: i have mentioned above that i have already tried assigning the text to variable. because there are many rules. In this way i must assign each rule to a new variable and its a long process. So i want to directly call the rule function in a label. so the whole output of rule function will display in label by clicking the button.

Comment: Even if you are able to call the function in that `Label`, it will still take the same time to compute and produce the result.
If you could post the complete `rules` function, I will try to optimize it for you.